# Constructor property is null when called from a method

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
    class user {
        public $connection;
        public $host;
        public $username;
        public $password;
        public $database;
        public $port;

        public function __constructor() {
            $this->host     = "localhost"; 
            $this->username = "root";
            $this->password = "Password";
            $this->database = "database";
            $this->port     = "port";

            // Create connection
            $this->connection = new mysqli($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database, $this->port);

            // Check connection
            if ($this->connection->connect_error)
            {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $this->connection->connect_error;
            }
        }

        public function save ( $data ) {            
            $prop = strval($data['prop']);

            $sql = "INSERT INTO user (prop)
                    VALUES ('" .$prop. "')";

            if (!mysqli_query($this->connection, $sql))
            {
                die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($this->connection));
            }
            echo "1 record added";

            mysqli_close($this->connection);
        }
    }
?>
```

When running the code above I get the following warnings:

> PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null
>   given in 'path' on line 32
>  PHP Warning:  mysqli_error() expects
>   parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in 'path' on line 34

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: `public function __construct()`!

Comment: No you don't, because this code does not actually instantiate any `user`s. Where is your [testcase](http://sscce.org)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using wrong magic function for PHP constructor it should be

```
__construct
```

and not

```
__constructor
```

Check [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#object.construct) for more reference

Comment: Your a legend bro, can't believe I missed something so simple.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
function __construct() {}
```

instead of:

```
function __constructor() {}
```

Please refer to [the PHP class documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php).